# iOS: Retain count much different depending on how assigned

Tags: ios

If I do this:

```
obj.var = [[[SomeClass alloc] init] autorelease];
```

and print the retainCount, I see -1.

However if I do the normal thing, and just say

```
var = [[[SomeClass alloc] init] autorelease];
```

...I see 1 as expected.

Why the difference, I ask you. It intrigues and beguiles me so.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean with `obj`? When you have to access a instance variable synthesized with `@property` you have to use `self.var`.

Comment: **retainCount** is useless.  Don't call it.

Comment: Please read this: [retainCount is useless](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2011/12/18/retaincount-is-useless/)

Comment: Ah! Turned out the property (I did not write this code) was using COPY instead of RETAIN. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 2):

Don't look at the retain count, seriously. It's not useful for 99% of applications. Not only does it not necessarily reflect a value in this moment in time, but you don't know what else has retained it, or released it in other parts of the run loop. The framework does its own management as well.

Comment: Retain count did help me, because it focused my attention on the one variable and I realized that the property was set to copy rather than retain. That was the original bug.

Comment: Instruments would have helped you here too.

Answer (score 2):

The -1 that you're seeing is actually `UINT_MAX` as retain counts are unsigned ([see here for confirmation](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/24005-nscolor-objects-have-negative-retaincount-1.html#23920)). In fact, a possible reason is given on that page too (performance optimisation leading to cached instances).

In the end, it's not worth looking at retain count. It's not useful for debugging, in fact downright misleading, since system frameworks may be retaining and releasing your objects without your knowledge.

Answer (score -2):

It's a problem of the past!!! check out [ARC iOS5](http://thinkvitamin.com/code/ios/ios-5-automatic-reference-counting-arc/)

cheers,
Fy

Comment: ...whilst as a few people have pointed out, `retainCount` is useless, I don't think just saying 'Go use ARC' is a helpful answer at all. There are plenty of reasons to not use ARC at this point, perhaps the OP needs to support certain OS versions for instance.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. Whether ARC should be used instead is a different matter (I believe not using it leads to a better understanding), but the OP wants to know WHY this happens.